# How does Maven determine the order goals run in within a given phase?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I understand that Maven has a number of phases that run in the order they are defined for a given [lifecycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Build_Lifecycles), and that you can attach goals to a phase.

What happens when you attach a number of goals to a phase, how does Maven determine what order to run the goals in?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From "[Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins)":

> The goals that are configured will be added to the goals already bound to the lifecycle from the packaging selected. If more than one goal is bound to a particular phase, the order used is that those from the packaging are executed first, followed by those configured in the POM. Note that you can use the `<executions>` element to gain more control over the order of particular goals.